# Почему хост разрывает соединение?

Tags: python

Работает минуты 2-3, обрабатывает ссылок 10-15 и потом уходит в ошибку, нужно прокси подкрутить к скрипту или что нужно сделать подскажите, не профессионал в кодинге, ВПН пробывал включать всё тоже самое(((

Ошибка такого рода:

> ERROR mascraper - analyze_profile: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение', None, 10054, None))

```
import argparse
import random
import logging
import os
import sys
import shutil
 
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'
 
import nsfw_model
import vscoscrape
 
 
def calc_nsfw_index(classification: dict) -> float:
    """ {'drawings': 0.04, 'hentai': 0.03, 'neutral': 0.47, 'porn': 0.42, 'sexy': 0.02}  ->  0.48 """
    return sum((classification['hentai'], classification['porn'], classification['sexy']))
 
 
def parse_profile_name(profile: str) -> str:
    if 'vsco.co/' not in profile:
        return profile
    return profile.partition('vsco.co/')[2].partition('/')[0]
 
 
def is_image(filename: str) -> bool:
    return filename.lower().endswith(('.png', '.jpg', '.jpeg'))
 
 
def get_vsco_file_name(file_info: list) -> str:
    return file_info[1] + '.' + file_info[0].rpartition('.')[2]
 
 
def analyze_profile(model, profile: str, sample_proportion: float = 0.2, floor: float = 0.75, maxposts: int = 1000):
    started_dir = os.getcwd()
    try:
        scraper = vscoscrape.Scraper(parse_profile_name(profile))
        scraper.getImageList()
        logging.info(f"Analyzing username: {scraper.username}")
        images = list(filter(lambda info: is_image(info[0]), scraper.imagelist))
        if len(images) == 0:
            logging.warning('No images found')
        if len(images) < maxposts:
            for i, image_info in enumerate(random.sample(images, int(len(images) * sample_proportion))):
                scraper.download_img_normal(image_info)
                classification = list(nsfw_model.classify(model,
                                                      f"{scraper.path}/{get_vsco_file_name(image_info)}").values())[0]
                nsfw_index = calc_nsfw_index(classification)
                logging.debug(f"NSFW index: {nsfw_index}, filename: {get_vsco_file_name(image_info)}")
                if nsfw_index > floor:
                    logging.info(f"NSFW FOUND, index: {nsfw_index}, "
                                 f"pics scanned: {i + 1}, "
                                 f"filename: {get_vsco_file_name(image_info)}")
                    scraper.getImages()
                    return
            else:
                logging.info(f"NO NSFW FOUND, "
                            f"pics scanned: {int(len(images) * sample_proportion)}")
                if os.getcwd() != started_dir:
                    directory = os.getcwd()
                os.chdir(started_dir)
                shutil.rmtree(directory, ignore_errors=True)
        else:
            logging.info(f"TOO MUCH POSTS. MAX is {maxposts}")
            if os.getcwd() != started_dir:
                    directory = os.getcwd()
            os.chdir(started_dir)
            shutil.rmtree(directory, ignore_errors=True)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(e)
        raise
    finally:
        if os.getcwd() != started_dir:
            os.chdir(started_dir)
 
 
def parse_args(args: list):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('floor', nargs='?', type=float, default=0.8,
                        help='РїРѕСЂРѕРі РґР»СЏ nsfw_index (РїРѕРґСЂРѕР±РЅРµРµ РІ README.txt)')
    parser.add_argument('sample', nargs='?', type=float, default=0.2,
                        help='РїСЂРѕС†РµРЅС‚ РїРёРєС‡, РєРѕС‚РѕСЂС‹Рµ Р±СѓРґСѓС‚ РїСЂРµРґСЃРєР°С‡Р°РЅС‹ (РїРѕРґСЂРѕР±РЅРµРµ РІ README.txt)')
    parser.add_argument('maxposts', nargs='?', type=int, default=200,
                        help='max post num')
    return parser.parse_args(args)
 
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.stderr = sys.stdout
 
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                        format='%(asctime)s.%(msecs)d %(levelname)s %(module)s - %(funcName)s: %(message)s',
                        datefmt='%H:%M:%S')
 
    parsed_args = parse_args(sys.argv[1:])
 
    model = nsfw_model.load_model('./model_mobilenet_v2_140_224.h5')
 
    while True:
        link = input('Enter link:\n')
        try:
            analyze_profile(model, link, parsed_args.sample, parsed_args.floor, parsed_args.maxposts)
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(e)
```

Comment: представьте себе на месте сайта - к Вам приходит человек и начинают без останова задавать вопросы разные. И не останавливается. Хотите тянуть с сайта "важную для себя инфу" - делайте это аккуратно и потихоньку. И лучше договоритесь с владельцами сайта.

Comment: Это и я понимаю, вопрос то стоит, как пофиксить, т.к. с браузера вручную нет такой проблемы. А через код есть, прошу подправить код или дать наводку что добавить в код.

Comment: Добавьте sleep. Да, это будет медленне, но скорее всего будет работать. Если и это не даст результата, то нужно будет изучить, как работает защита сайта и дописывать код. Или просто написать админам